# Analyzing the results of Likert scale with one sample Wilcoxon signed-rank test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likert, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have the results of a questionary with 2 subjects and each of them includes 4 sub-questions in the form of Likert items. The questions are about the impact of a situation on people's lives and the options are negative, little negative, neutral, little positive, and positive.
My main question is how to interpret the results to understand the direction of impact. I encoded them (negative=-2, little negative=-1, neutral=0, little positive=1, and positive=2) and used one-sample Wilcoxon signed-rank test and put the difference equal to 0 in python.
I appreciate any help

Comment: If I understand this correctly, a bar chart showing the frequency of different answers is as informative as you need or will get. It will show clearly whether positive or negative answers are dominant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Comment.** I agree with @NickCox that some sort of graphical
display may be the best you can do. If I understand
correctly, you have one four-question questionnaire
from each of two people. Even if the two subjects
have completely non-overlapping opinions, I know of no
appropriate test that would find a statistically significant difference

A paired
Wilcoxon signed-rank test will not be able to
give a P-value below 5%.

Consider the following fictitious data, with a paired
Wilcoxon test in R, which shows no significant difference:

```
a = c(-1, -1, 0,  0)
b = c( 1,  1, 2,  2)
wilcox.test(a, b, pair=T)

       Wilcoxon signed rank test 
       with continuity correction

data:  a and b
V = 0, p-value = 0.07186
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location shift is not equal to 0

Warning message:
In wilcox.test.default(a, b, pair = T) :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, then please consider 
[upvoting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) 
and/or 
[accepting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) 
it.